# Remove Catkin artifacts from CPack build

Tags: cmake, ros, deb, cpack

I am trying to build a Debian package using CPack from a catkin workspace.
This project uses ROS in some part of the implementation.

The package gets build, but the problem I'm having is that ROS adds some files to the .deb.

- .catkin
- local/.rosinstall
- local/env.sh
- local/setup.{sh,bash,zsh}
- local/_setup_util.py

I'm thinking there's got to be a way to either ignore those files from installing, or simply remove them from the .deb output, but I can't seem to find any option for it.

The CMake configuration looks like this:

```
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node  DESTINATION bin)
    INSTALL(FILES doc/${PROJECT_NAME}.yaml DESTINATION share)
    INSTALL(FILES doc/${PROJECT_NAME}.service DESTINATION lib/systemd/system)

    SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Maintainer")
    SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question in [answer.ros](https://answers.ros.org/question/292010/remove-ros-artifact-from-cmake-install/) as well. Short answer: add `-DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE=1` to `catkin_make`.

or `SET(CATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE true)` in `CMakeLists.txt`